# Trying to find all elements on a page that matches a certain regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a javascript bookmarklet that will go through and find all elements on a webpage with text that looks like a currency. Then with each element, I find its font size and determine whether it has a line-through. The price and font-size are pushed into an array.

I have put together the code below but I am not sure if it is the most efficient. There is also an error with the match. Ideally, I would like to be able to hone in straight on those elements that match with the regex.

```
var ele = b.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(i=0; i<ele.length; i++) {
    //check iff innerhtml matches
    if(ele[i].innerHTML.match(/[$€£]\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})?(\.\d{2})?/g)) {
        var price = ele[i].innerHTML;
        var size = ele[i].style.fontSize;
        var lineThrough = ele[i].style.textDecoration;
        if(lineThrough != 'line-through' && price && size) {
            results.push({ size: size, price: price});
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the match seems to not match exactly.

Comment: Instead of testing the innerHTML you should test the textContent/innerText, otherwise you will match symbols in attribute values as well as in the text. Also, the style object only gives you values for style properties set directly on the element's style object. You need to look at the current or computed style as appropriate. There is also the obsolete strike element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you would like to match a sums grater than 999,999.99, regexp should be: `[$€£](\d{1,3})(,?\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?`. Here I changed `?` to `*` that means "0 or more", when "?" means "zero or one".

If you want to find a price that is not written in a strict format (e.g. $30 000 000), than you may want to add admission for "possibly" spaces: `[$€£]\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(,?\d{3}\s*)*(\.\d{2})?`.

Object `style` contains only the styles specified directly for this element, but does not contains inherited styles. To get access to inherited styles, use `window.getComputedStyle`.

`innerHTML` property returns content of all nested nodes, so your function will find all parent elements of element you looking for. To find the current node text I use `firstChild` property if this property is `instance of Text` (but I'm believe there's a more elegant solution):

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
results = [];

for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++)
{
    var el = ele[i];
    if (el.hasChildNodes && el.firstChild instanceof Text)
    {
        var price = el.firstChild.textContent.match(/([$€£]+)\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(,?\d{3}\s*)*(\.\d{2})?/g);
        if (price)
        {
            var style = window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(el) : el.style;
            var size = style.fontSize;
            var lineThrough = style.textDecoration;
            if (lineThrough != 'line-through' && price && size)
            {
                results.push({ size: size, price: price});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to find amounts that contains abbreviations, you can expand your regex to: `/([$€£]+)\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(,?\d{3}\s*)*(\.\d{2})?(\s*[K|M|MM|B|thousand|million|billion])*/g`.

Comment: Excellent answer. It looks like it did what I was looking for.